# variations on public static main (String args[])

Tags: java, program-entry-point

What is the difference between these 4 method signatures, and why does the 4th not work?

```
public void main(String args[]) {... } 
public void main(String[] args) {... }
public void main(String... args) {... }
public void main(String[] args[]) {... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first three are equivalent.<sup>*</sup>  The last one is equivalent to `String[][] args` (i.e. an array of arrays), which doesn't match what Java requires for `main`.

However, the idiomatic version is the second one.

---

<sub>* The third one is only valid from Java 5 onwards.</sub>

Comment: The 4th variant's syntax is perfectly valid. Its signature simply differs from the required main function signature `public void main(java.lang.String[]);`.

Comment: So, what is the required main function signature?  And isn't that something that should be checked at compile time?  The 4th compiles ok.

Comment: @Pregnantmom: Any of the first 3.  The 4th compiles fine because Java supports method overloading.  But the Java runtime expects to be able to find a method called `main` that takes a `String[]`, and throws an error if it can't.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth -- The 4th compiles fine because it's (barely) legal Java.  Has nothing to do with overloading.

Comment: @Hot: @Pregnantmom is asking why it's not detected at compile-time; the reason is because there's nothing to prevent you providing `main` with different signatures.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth -- Yeah, I was just correcting his mention of overloading -- the fact that #4 (apparently) compiles has nothing to do with overloading.

Answer (score 1):

`String args[]` and `String[] args` are exactly equivalent.  The first form is the "C" form of array declaration, with the `[]` applied to the variable name.  The second form is the preferred Java form, where the `[]` is (more logically) associated with the type name rather than the variable name.  Java allows both forms interchangeably.

The third form appears to be a variable-length parameter list form, though I've never delved into that area.

The forth form is an abomination that only sneaks through the cracks of the spec and should never be used.  My guess is that it specifies a 2-dimensional array, but one can't be sure without trying it.

Note that there's nothing sacred about `public static main`.  You can name any method `main` and call it from anywhere.  It's just that when you run a Java program from the command line the JAVA command looks for something of that name (with the usual parameter layout) as the entry point.  Up until then `main` is treated like any other method.

Comment: it is a 2d array.  I tried it as you suggest, as a 2nd main method in a class, passing it a 2d array of strings.  Works fine.  Why is this an abomination?  Because it's a throwback to c?

Comment: It's an abomination to use the notation `String[] args[]` because there is the perfectly good option of saying `String[][] args` or (if you're a dyed-in-the-wool C programmer) `String args[][]`.  Either of those can be easily understood by most programmers, whereas `String[] args[]` is confusing at best and will leave many experienced programmers (including myself) wondering "What the hell does that mean??"