# main(String[] args) or main(String args[])

Tags: java, arrays

I'm watching Java tutorials right now and I've noticed that some people use:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and some people use:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

I was just wondering if there is any difference between them.

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290492/variations-on-public-static-main-string-args

Comment: When declaring an array either `type[] variable` or `type variable[]` is allowed, though the first form is generally preferred.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thank you i didn't see that post :)

Comment: (The second form it allowed to make old C programmers happy, since C only allows the second form.  But the second form is confusing, since the variable being declared has a type of "array of type".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference, it is array of string.

`String[] args` or `String args[]` are equivalents.